# Please help me in understanding this output on Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators

I have this code below for which the output generated is 17 5 but I am unable to figure out why the value of x is 17 after the final interpretation and not 18. Please help me in understanding the logic behind this

```
x,y=7,2
x,y,x=x+1,y+3,x+10
print(x,y)
```

Output Generated is : 17 5 
Why not 18 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the first line, `x` is 7, `y` is 2.

In the second line, you are setting `x,y,x` to `x+1,y+3,x+10`.

The expressions on the right are evaluated, giving `8,5,17`.

You assign 8 to `x`, 5 to `y`, and 17 to `x`.

So at the end, `x==17` and `y==5`.